# HTML Checkbox onclick send everytime the same value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to use two checkboxs with a value = "on". The other one is for rember after submit a form. Every time i click on this checkbox, they will always send "on".

What i do wrong ?
Here is my code

```js
var rdt = {
  updateScroll: function() {
    alert('klick scroll:' + gbi('scrollit').value);
    gbi('main').removeChild(gbi('icontent'));
    var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.id = 'icontent';
    ifr.src = gbi('urlinput').value;
    ifr.scrolling = (gbi('scrollit').value == 'on') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    gbi('scroll_hid').value = (gbi('scrollit').value == 'on') ? 'on' : 'off';
    gbi('main').appendChild(ifr);
    rdt.resizeView();
  }


}

function gbi(iD) {
  return document.getElementById(iD);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="scrollit" onclick="rdt.updateScroll()" checked>
<input type="hidden" name="scroll" id="scroll_hid" value="<?php echo $scroll ?>">
```

The parameter $scroll can predifine over URL, but the result was the same if i use it or if i dont use it.

Comment: where is the second checkbox in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are getting its `value` and its `value` is `on`. You have to get the value when it is checked like:

```
var value = null;
$('#scrollit').click(function(){
    if($(this).is('checked'))
    {
        value = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

In this case you will get its value when it is checked otherwise `null`

Comment: Hi, i try to do this: if(gbi('scrollit').is('checked'))
    {  value = $(this).val();
        alert("here i am");    } but the alert wont display  - did i understand you in a wrong way?

Comment: Sorry, ive update my code, there are two checkboxes insider my sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

The primary intention of checkbox is to make user that the option to be checked or unchecked it is not intended to send values

You can refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) for more details

Here is the main thing

> The HTML input element  allows you to select a
>   single value for submission in a form (or not).

A solution for your problem is as follows you can check checkbox's current status ie checked or not  by using following

based on your code

```
gbi('scrollit').checked
```

```js
var rdt = {
  updateScroll: function() {
    alert('klick scroll:' + gbn('scrollit').value);
    gbi('main').removeChild(gbi('icontent'));
    var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.id = 'icontent';
    ifr.src = gbi('urlinput').value;
    ifr.scrolling = (gbi('scrollit').value == 'on') ? 'yes' : 'no';
    gbi('scroll_hid').value = (gbi('scrollit').value == 'on') ? 'on' : 'off';
    gbi('main').appendChild(ifr);
    rdt.resizeView();
  }
}

function gbi(iD) {
  return document.getElementById(iD);
}


function gbn(name) {
  var x = document.getElementsByName(name);
  var i;
  var element;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].type == "checkbox") {
      element = x[i];
    }
  }
  return element;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="scroll" id="scrollit" onclick="rdt.updateScroll()" checked>
<input type="hidden" name="scroll" id="scroll_hid" value="<?php echo $scroll ?>">
```

Comment: Sorry, ive update my code, there are two checkboxes insider my sourcecode.

Comment: @newbieRB anyway you are acessing by id scrollit

Comment: @newbieRB `document.getElementsByName("scroll");` to get value and use 'name=scroll' for both checkbox and verify with visibility hidden  check

Comment: @Samiel J Mathew as result i get "[object NodeList]"!?

Answer (score 0):

add a small loop make the code more clear for me and works already

```
updateScroll: 

    function() {


                gbi('main').removeChild(gbi('icontent'));
                var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
                ifr.id='icontent';
                ifr.src=gbi('urlinput').value;

        if (gbi('scrollit').value=='on' && gbi('scroll_hid').value!='on')
        { ifr.scrolling='yes'; gbi('scroll_hid').value='on';}
        else
        { ifr.scrolling='no'; gbi('scroll_hid').value='';}

                //ifr.scrolling=(gbi('scrollit').value=='on')?'yes':'no';
                //gbi('scroll_hid').value=(gbi('scrollit').value=='on')?'on':'off';
                gbi('main').appendChild(ifr);
                rdt.resizeView();
            },
            rotate: function() {
                rdt.w = parseInt(gbi('icontent').style.width);
                rdt.h = parseInt(gbi('icontent').style.height);
                gbi('icontent').style.width=gbi('icontentfoot').style.width = rdt.h+'px';
                gbi('icontent').style.height = rdt.w+'px';
            }
```